# SQL and NoSQL which one is more suitable for this case and why?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

In my project:

> 1. Data is not going to be modified (only query).
> 2. It is going to be more than 1.000.000 instances of data.
> 3. Query performance is critical.
> 4. In case of using SQL, it is going to be a single table with 7 columns. (no joints)

---

There are also different classification approaches used in NoSQL. Which are given below with some examples:

> **Column:** Accumulo, Cassandra, HBase
>   
> **Document:** Clusterpoint, Couchdb, Couchbase, MarkLogic, MongoDB
>   
> **Key-value:** Dynamo, FoundationDB, MemcacheDB, Redis, Riak, FairCom c-treeACE
>   
> **Graph:** Allegro, Neo4J, OrientDB, Virtuoso, Stardog
>   
>  Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#cite_note-7

First of all, does the database system really makes an observable amount of performance difference for this case?
If it makes then,can you please explain which one is more suitable for my project SQL or NoSQL, if NoSQL then which classification approach?

Thank you in advance

Comment: if you are going to vote down than please add the reason as comment

Comment: good thing there are no joints as it could slow things up a bit :)

Comment: This looks like a [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) question. Or rather Gorilla vs. Shark vs. Octopus vs. Horse vs. Elephant vs. Camel vs. Lobster vs. Cockroach vs. Tentacle Monster from Outer Space.

Comment: Gorilla vs. Shark vs. Octopus vs. Horse vs. to do a specified task like climbing a tree

Answer (score 3):

I am currently enrolled in a project to set up a "standard" Database with a huge amount of data. We start by implementing in SQL to see the performance of the queries. Once this is done we address the problem of performance.

There is multiple reasons for this, but to name a few:

1. Standard SQL is easily implemented and standard across multiple instances (as of present day)
2. If you know SQL, make a fast implementation. To save time and get the project going.
3. There are loads of information available about SQL implementations.

I cannot answer about NoSQL but hopefully someone can fill me in.

Answer (score 1):

The important question you need to ask is what kind of queries you will be performing. For example ClusterPoint offers real-time aggregation, so if you need result grouping and extracting summaries, it gives you great performance.

For a regular key/value they should all perform pretty well, so pick the one you are most comfortable with.